# How to install CMake from binary distribution on Linux

Tags: linux, cmake

I've downloaded an already compiled binary distribution of CMake from [this link](https://cmake.org/download/). The package contains a bin, doc, man and share folders. I can unpack them and use them directly from a specific folder, but I'd rather install it globally.

What's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those folders can be extracted in the `/usr` folder. It can be easily done with tar using:

```
cd /usr
tar --strip-components=1 -xzf ~user/Downloads/cmake-3.19.6-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

The `--strip-components=1` argument strips the containing folder from the archive.

Comment: The absolutely "best" way to install anything on any Linux, is by use of the distribution's package manager; `apt`, `yum`, ... This will ensure (to some higher level than above)  that you will have a working "thing" (e.g. CMake) and that you may remove it easily if somethings still goes wrong.

Comment: @Hannu sorry dude, your sarcasm is absolute nonsense, just try to build the latest cmake under CentOS 7. As per yum - it will gladly install the 2.x version

Comment: There was absolutely no sarcasm intended, that was in your reading. I firmly believe that "tar -x ..." -type installs make a mess.

Comment: This IS nonsense. apt and yum will install whatever is the default for the repo on the distro you are using and that may be an ancient version of cmake.